# Azure Basic ASP.NET WCF Data Service generating HTTP 500.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, wcf-data-services

First off, I would like to say thank you in advance for your advice and guidance.  I am new to the Microsoft .Net stack.

I have created a very simple WCF Service that is hosted on a Azure website and that should create endpoints to an Azure SQL datasource.

In VS 2013, I first created an ADO.NET EDM point to my Azure SQL:

```cs
namespace WorkOrderIntegration
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class WorkOrderEntities : DbContext
    {
        public WorkOrderEntities()
            : base("name=WorkOrderEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added the [WCF Data Service 5.6] to the project and only made a few changes to the InitializeService method:

```cs
namespace WorkOrderIntegration
{
    //Added my Entity to the class declaration
    public class WorkOrderService : DataService<WorkOrderEntities>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            //Added these next 2 lines
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);

            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
}
```

I then publish my project to my Azure hosted [website](http://workordertest.azurewebsites.net/) and navigate to the /WorkOrderService.svc/WorkOrders, I get a HTTP 500.0 error.

Everything builds fine and I have read through several articles that use this same process to success.  Any help or direction you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some days of frustration and google search, I found the solution as described below:

I first added the ServerBehavior flags to get the actual error.

```cs
// Added the below line
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] 
namespace WorkOrderIntegration
{

    public class WorkOrderService : DataService<WorkOrderEntities>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
}
```

I then recieved the real error:
`The exception message is 'Expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' cannot be used for return type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext''.`

After some more searching, its turns out that this error was due to trying to create a `WCF Data Service 5.6` on top of `Entity Framework 6+`.  So the solution as described in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx) article was to install the [WCF Data Services EntityFramework Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider/1.0.0-beta2) module in Visual Studio.

After making these changes, I am no longer getting the mysterious, generic HTTP 500 Errors.